# normal baking, low poly to high poly. Sub surface corners not correct

Tags: baking, normal-map

I have a simple cube that I duplicated. I unwrapped the low poly. Applied sub surf modifier to high poly. Added some edge loops to get the edges smooth.

However when I bake from high to low poly the corners of the low poly seem to be poking through the high poly normals.

[image: Normal Baked]

[image: High Poly]

[image: Low Poly]

Here's my blender file:[image]

Comment: What is your margin value set to? Are you able to add a screenshot of your bake settings or even upload your file?

Comment: I tried different margins thinking it was bleed but the margin settings didn't resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked your file and after baking everything looks pretty good. I can see that you added one more edgeloop to the high poly object and that seems to have fixed the issue. I only managed to replicate your image when the edgeloop was removed. When baking you still want to keep the objects as close as possible. There are some things that just aren't possible, like making a cube look like a sphere. Without that last edgeloop the cubes are just too different to get a good bake.